# javascript function doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I'll rephrase my question

I wrote this code and I don't understand why it doesn't work...

I want to create something that one a person come's to the website to order sandwich he write's one of the options I wrote in the website and then it display's the sandwich he chose and the the ingredients in the sandwich (the ingredients are all the arrays)

I'll add my html code as well, and if someone can write an example for the right code it will be much more helpful to me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

JavaScript code:

```
var avucado =  ["eggs ","avucado ","tommato ","mayonnaise ","pickles ","gamba"];
var eggSalad =  ["eggs ","dill ","mayonnaise ","pickles"];
var tuna =   ["tuna ","coriander ","pickles ","mayonnaise ","gamba"];
var cheeze = ["yellow cheeze ","mayonnaise ","tommato ","cucumber"];
var sausage =["sausage ","mustard ","mayonnaise ","tommato ","pickles"];
var choice1 = ("you chose:");
var choice2 = ("the ingredients of your sandwich are:") 



var food = function(foodName)
{

if (document.getElementById("input").value = avucado) {

    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'avucado.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + avucado + ".");


}else if(document.getElementById("input").value = eggSalad) {

    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'egg salad.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + eggSalad + ".");


}else if(document.getElementById("input").value = tuna) {

    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'tuna.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + tuna + ".");


}else if(document.getElementById("input").value = cheeze) {

    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'yellow cheeze.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + cheeze + ".");


}else if(document.getElementById("input").value = sausage) {

    document.write(choice1 + " " + 'tuna.'+ "<br /><br />" + " " + choice2 + 
    " " + tuna + ".");
}

else(document.getElementById("input".value != avucado,eggSalad,tuna,cheeze,sausage){

    document.write("Error, please chose one of the sandwich's on the list");
    }


};
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World!</title>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>


</head>

<body dir="rtl">
<h1> wich sandwich would you like to order? </h1>
<form>
<input type="text" id="input" /><br />
<button type="button" id="button" value="submit" onclick="food()">submit</button><br />

</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The last `else` has many syntax errors. You are missing an `if` after it and you did not close the `getElementById("input"` with another `)`. Also, the commas do nothing there...

Comment: One, you are setting values inside if statements. To compare you have to use double = `==` or triple = `==`. Two, you are comparing a string value (guess) to an array, which will always return false. I fyou want to check if a text value is inside of an array, you can use `arr.indexOf(str);` On top of that, there are a bunch of syntax errors in that else statement as @PhistucK pointed out

Comment: Also, `document.write` does not work asynchronously (and it is generally discouraged). You should have an element for the output and set its `innerHTML` or `textContent` or something instead.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all occurrences of:

```
document.getElementById("input").value =
```

With:

```
document.getElementById("input").value ==
```

The single "equals" sign (`=`) is an ["Assignment" operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators)
The double "equals" sign (`==`) is an ["Comparison" operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators)

In your `if`'s, you were assigning the foodstuffs' contents to the input's `.value`, instead of checking for equality.

To check if the `value` is in the arrays, you should do something like this:

```
if(avucado.indexOf(document.getElementById("input").value) !== -1){
```

So, if the value is in the array `avucado`, then do what's below the `if`.

Last, this `else` statement of yours needs some fixing:

```
else(document.getElementById("input".value != avucado,eggSalad,tuna,cheeze,sausage){
    document.write("Error, please chose one of the sandwich's on the list");
}
```

Replace that with:

```
else if(avucado.concat(eggSalad,tuna,cheeze,sausage).indexOf(document.getElementById("input").value) == -1){
    document.write("Error, please chose one of the sandwich's on the list");
}
```

Now, instead of `document.write("text")`, I'd suggest using DOM manipulation:

In your HTML, add an element like this:

```
<span id="message"></span>
```

Then, in your JS:

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "text";
```

Comment: sorry I didnt mention it before but I tried to change it to == as it should be but it still dosent work..

Comment: This is a very partial answer that does not solve all of the issues.

Comment: @PhistucK: Added another part to the answer.

Comment: Could the persons that downvoted me please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: Still not enough, there are major syntax errors in the last `else`, as I mentioned in the comment to the question.

Comment: @PhistucK: That should've fixed the `else`.

Comment: See my last comment about `document.write` to the question.

Comment: @PhistucK: That's really a (pretty large) cosmetic problem, but not part of the actual problem as to why his code doesn't work.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, if the output does not get printed, the code does not work.

Comment: Hm, `doc.write` doesn't output the string anywhere? Any way, added a quick DOM alternative.

Comment: `document.write` may override the entire page instead of appending to the page, or may just do nothing. I do not remember the circumstances.